# RSI-prevention wise, should I be using my pink finger or my ring finger for pressing keys/buttons?

Tags: strength, injury-prevention, tendons, fingers

Recently I've started playing a game called Beatmania, where you repeatedly press 7 different buttons and also here and there spin a disc.
[image]

It's possible to press the buttons with a lot of different hand positioning methods, but right now i'm having trouble deciding to either use my thumb, index, middle and ring finger for the four buttons on the right-hand side or my thumb, index, middle and pink finger.

What would be better for my hands in the long-term? Rapidly pressing with my middle and pink finger feels a lot more fluent than with my ring finger (assuming because of the shared tendons), but my pink finger is a lot weaker and takes more power to press down than with my ring finger.

Comment: I am honestly conflicted as to whether this counts as a good Fitness question...

Comment: @SeanDuggan - Yeah, I hovered over the option myself, but I was in doubt, and I tend to give the asker the benefit of the doubt. I propose to keep it open, as I'd quite frankly be interested in a well thought-out answer.